Python and Tensorflow Image classifier got Error during training: Argument `output` must have rank (ndim) `target.ndim - 1
I am creating a model using Python and Tensorflow to scan a folder structure with images and metadata associated to those images that are saved in a text file (CSV). I am trying to train the model using both the images stored in a certain folder alongside with the metadata associated, but when it comes to the prediction, I will need only a image to execute it. This is the code of my model:
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Activating eager function as console suggest
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

# A simple function to load the image and process it
def load_image(image_path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [224, 224])  # Resizing to standard h x w
    image = image / 255.0  # Normaliza
    return image

# Loading metadata
def load_metadata(metadata_path):
    metadata = pd.read_csv(metadata_path, header=None)
    metadata = metadata.values.flatten()
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(metadata, dtype=tf.float32)

# Function to load data from directory
def load_data_from_directory(directory):
    images = []
    labels = []
    metadata = []
    
    categories = os.listdir(directory)
    for category in categories:
        category_path = os.path.join(directory, category)
        subfolders = os.listdir(category_path)
        
        for subfolder in subfolders:
            subfolder_path = os.path.join(category_path, subfolder)
            for file in os.listdir(subfolder_path):
                if file.endswith(".jpg"):
                    img_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, file)
                    img = load_image(img_path)
                    images.append(img)
                    
                    metadata_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, file.replace(".jpg", ".txt"))
                    if os.path.exists(metadata_path):
                        meta = load_metadata(metadata_path)
                        metadata.append(meta)
                    else:
                        # If no metadata found, then assign zero
                        metadata.append(np.zeros(9))
                    
                   
                    label = categories.index(category)
                    labels.append(label)
    
    images = np.array(images)
    metadata = np.array(metadata)
    labels = np.array(labels)
    
    print(f"Loaded {len(images)} images")
    print(f"Loaded {len(metadata)} metadata entries")
    print(f"Loaded {len(labels)} labels")

    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, metadata, labels))

# Create a dataset
directory = 'c:/Alisado'
dataset = load_data_from_directory(directory)

# Defining the model
def create_model():
    input_image = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_image)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    
    # A branch for classification
    x_class = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    output_class = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax', name='class_output')(x_class)
    
    # A branch for metadata
    x_meta = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    output_meta = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='sigmoid', name='meta_output')(x_meta)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_image, outputs=[output_class, output_meta])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss={'class_output': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 'meta_output': 'binary_crossentropy'},
                  metrics={'class_output': 'accuracy', 'meta_output': 'accuracy'})
    return model

model = create_model()

# Prepare dataset for training
def preprocess_dataset(dataset):
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    dataset = dataset.batch(32)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset

train_dataset = preprocess_dataset(dataset)

# Train the model
try:
    model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=100)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during training: {e}")

# Save the model
model.save('archaeological_model.h5')

But whenever I am executing the first epoch I am getting the error:
Error during training: Argument output must have rank (ndim) target.ndim - 1. Received: target.shape=(32, 9), output.shape=(32, 6)
I am very new to this kind of programming, so any clue or if anyone has experience with this particular error, I would really appreciate their input, I already looked up some posts in the site, but I could not find something that can help me at the moment.
Additional info:
The data is in a folder structure like this:
c:/parent/category1/photogroup1 which contains various pictures and a single metadata file associated to those pictures.
I can also have c:/parent/category1/photogroup2 with another set of pictures and a single metadata file associated to those pictures
I have many categories as well.
The metadata file is just a CSV format which sets 1 if the group of pictures share an attribute, this is an example of the content of the file:
1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1
